# Не функционирует перемещение Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Написал скрипт на шарпе, прикрепил его к обьекту игрока, по задумке изображение должно перемещаться по нажатию на стрелку вправо, но ничего не происходит.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class playerCont : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 20f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent <Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    void Update () {
        float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.MovePosition (rb.position + Vector2.right * MoveX  * speed * 
    Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Скопировал ваш код - всё работает.

Вы уверены, что у вас в `Rigidbody2D` объекта не установлены галочки во `FreezePosition`?

`MovePosition(...)` двигает объект по всем правилам физики, с применением интерполяции, а значит если заблокировать положение `Rigidbody2D` , то объект через него не сдвинуть.